# XMPP Unsubscribe - remove buddy on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

my bot periodically sends add xmpp requests using XMPP service.

```
// Get XMPP service
    XMPPService xmpp = XMPPServiceFactory.getXMPPService();

    // Send Invitation
    xmpp.sendInvitation(toJid, fromJid);
```

Over a period of time, the roster has grown very big.

I do not see a value to unsubscribe the user from a roster.

Is there a way to delete the user from the roster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is unfortunately no.  What I believe you are asking is "Can I cancel a previously-granted subscription request?".

The answer (at this time) is that we don't support that.  You may want to star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7953) though.